# How to make GWT SuggestBox autoselect the first match from the suggestion display?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs

I am using GWT SuggestBox as an autoselect field in my app. I am using GWT 2.5.1. I have noticed that it does not autoselect the first match from the pop up display unless we press enter. For e.g. Lets  say the list contains 4 items:
1. Alabama
2. Alaska
3. Arizona
4. Arkansas

If I type A then, the first selection i.e. Alabama should appear in the textbox, with 'labama' selected in blue. It should be something similar to GXT Combobox.

http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:combobox

Unfortunately, all the methods of SuggestBox and SuggestionDisplay are private, so can't do much. Has anyone does this kind of thing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented the similar scenario.

You can use SuggestBox with and exposed a method which take inputs as MultiWordSuggestOracle list.

While initializing , just give all your suggestion list as input parameter and then if you type any alphabet ,it will give suggestions accordingly.

Below is the code:

```
              import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MultiWordSuggestOracle;
              import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox;



               public class MySuggestBox extends SuggestBox  {

public MySuggestBox() {

    super();

    super.setLimit(Constants.SUGGESTBOX_LIMIT);
    super.setValue(Constants.SUGGESTBOX_VALUE);
    super.setVisible(Constants.SUGGESTBOX_VISIBLE);
    super.setAutoSelectEnabled(Constants.SUGGESTBOX_AUTOSELECTENABLE);



}

public MySuggestBox(MultiWordSuggestOracle list) {

    super(list);

}

public MySuggestBox(String text) {

    this();

    super.setText(text);
    super.setTitle(text);
}

public MySuggestBox(String text,String title) {

    this(text);

    super.setTitle(title);

}



            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But, will it also select the rest of the text in the textbox? If I typed 'A', then the first selection 'Alabama' will appear and the text 'labama' should be selected. Then if I type 'l', 'abama' should be selected.